# Migrating AD from 2003 32bit to 2008 64bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, migration

Is there a recommended upgrade path to migrate my AD data from 2003 (32 bit) to 2008 (64 bit)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the following:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731188%28WS.10%29.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/migrating-active-directory-domain-controller-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2008.aspx

In a nutshell, it's really no different than adding a new domain controller (DC, your new 2008 64-bit box), letting AD sync - then finally demoting, de-registering, and disconnecting the old server.  This assumes that you have multiple servers available - or at least that you have a sufficient number of DCs available that you can remove one to re-install it with 2008, while not risking your existing infrastructure.

After you migrate - with no 2003 servers remaining, you'll want to consider upgrading your domain and forest to 2008 R2 functional levels, as they'll still be running in 2003 functional levels - even though they're on 2008 R2 servers.

Otherwise, if you're looking for an in-place upgrade of a (single) server, this is not supported across architectures (e.g. 32-bit to 64-bit).  (Basically, this is the only concern on your 32/64-bit question - as it doesn't have any impact on any of the above.)